# How to add route permanently

Tags: linux, ip, routing

I'm using gentoo linux
I want to add a route and have it persist after /etc/init.d/net.eth0 restart

I can add successfully

```
route add -net x.x.x.x/x gw x.x.x.x eth0
```

How can I make this persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [configure a static route](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Static_Routing), which is distribution specific.  The `route` command itself has no way to arrange that, but on Gentoo `/etc/conf.d/net` will allow static routes defined with `ip` to be added on network restart.